# Spring Cloud Data Flow Custom Scala Processor unable to send/receive data from Starter Apps (SCDF 2.5.1 & Spring Boot 2.2.6)

Tags: scala, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have been working on creating a simple custom processor in Scala for Spring Cloud Data Flow and have been running into issues with sending/receiving data from/to starter applications. I have been unable to see any messages propagating through the stream. The definition of the stream is `time --trigger.time-unit=SECONDS | pass-through-log | log` where `pass-through-log` is my custom processor.

I am using Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.5.1 and Spring Boot 2.2.6.

Here is the code used for the processor - I am using the functional model.

```
@SpringBootApplication
class PassThroughLog {

  @Bean
  def passthroughlog(): Function[String, String] = {
    input: String => {
      println(s"Received input `$input`")
      input
    }
  }
}

object PassThroughLog {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = SpringApplication.run(classOf[PassThroughLog], args: _ *)
}
```

*application.yml*

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        bindings:
          passthroughlog-in-0: input
          passthroughlog-out-0: output
```

*build.gradle.kts*

```
// scala
implementation("org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.10")

// spring
implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.SR5"))
implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-dependencies:Horsham.SR5"))
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-function-web:3.0.7.RELEASE")
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka:3.0.5.RELEASE")
```

I have posted the entire project to [github](https://github.com/jackdreinhardt/scdf-scala) if the code samples here are lacking. I also posted the logs there, as they are quite long.

When I bootstrap a local Kafka cluster and push arbitrary data to the `input` topic, I am able to see data flowing through the processor. However, when I deploy the application on Spring Cloud Data Flow, this is not the case. I am deploying the app via Docker in Kubernetes.

Additionally, when I deploy a stream with the definition `time --trigger.time-unit=SECONDS | log`, I see messages in the log sink. This has convinced me the problem lies with the custom processor.

Am I missing something simple like a dependency or extra configuration? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with my Dockerfile. For ease of configuration, I had a build argument to specify the jar file used in the `ENTRYPOINT`. To accomplish this, I used the shell version of `ENTRYPOINT`. Changing up my `ENTRYPOINT` to the exec version solved my issue.

The shell version of `ENTRYPOINT` does not play well with image arguments (`docker run <image> <args>`), and hence SCDF could not pass the appropriate arguments to the container.

Changing my Dockerfile from:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.5-jdk-slim as build
ARG JAR
ENV JAR $JAR
ADD build/libs/$JAR .
ENTRYPOINT java -jar $JAR
```

to

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.5-jdk-slim as build
ARG JAR
ADD build/libs/$JAR program.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "program.jar"]
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring Cloud Stream 3.x version in SCDF, there's an additional property that you will have to set to let SCDF know what channel bindings are configured as input and output channels.

See: [Functional Applications](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/functional-apps/scst-function-bindings/)

Pay attention specifically to the following properties:

> app.time-source.spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.timeSupplier-out-0=output
>
> app.log-sink.spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.logConsumer-in-0=input

In your case, you will have to map `passthroughlog-in-0` and `passthroughlog-out-0` function bindings to `input` and `output` respectively.

Comment: Is this not done with my current application.yml file or do I have to add those properties when I deploy the stream on SCDF?

Comment: I added these configurations while deploying, leading to the app definition `pass-through-log --spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.passthroughlog-in-0=input --spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.passthroughlog-out-0=output` and was still unable to see data flowing through